# Can I tell if I am out of scope?

Tags: java

Is there any way I can tell, from the inside of the object, whether I am out of scope?

I have an object that must be closed. If it is not closed then a leak is guaranteed. I would like to try to auto-close if possible.

One of my private instance variables is a thread that must be shut down during the close. I am guessing the existence of the thread will cause unclosed objects to never be gc'd.

Paul

Comment: What is "auto close" ? It is difficult to really understand what you want to achieve. A generic solution is to just add a cleanup method you call when you don't need the object anymore. This method will do what ever required like ending the thread, closing connections or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no notion of 'out of scope scope' in java, because all objects are on the heap. Once you say 'new', the only thing that will ever clean up for you will be the gc. You can use try/finally, and you can have a finalizer, etc, but that's that.

You need to read about the finalize method, and then perhaps also about phantom references.

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/enicholas/archive/2006/05/understanding_w.html

Comment: I do not want to wait for finalise, I want to close as soon as I am out of scope (or soon after). Besides, I think finalise will not be called as I am not a candidate for GC because of my inner thread.

Answer (score 2):

Java has no destructors.

If an object requires explicit cleanup beyond Java's automatic garbage collection of memory, then you can offer an explicit method -- e.g., close(), terminate() or dispose().

If your thread is preventing garbage collection of an object by holding a reference to it, it could instead hold a [weak reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), which does not prevent garbage collection.

With a weak reference, you can tell whether the referenced object has been garbage-collected. However, you can't tell whether it is *eligible* for garbage collection.

Comment: I don't think I am looking for a destructor, I am looking for a moment when I am no longer reachable, at which point I will call my own close.

Comment: That would be possible with reference counting, like that used by  boost::shared_ptr in C++. But a Java garbage collector may detect unreachability at an unpredictable time after it occurs, or never. So you can't rely on finalizers, and you need explicit methods like java.io.InputStream.close().

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such mechanism in Java.

You can, however, put emergency cleanup in a shutdown hook.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html for details.

Note that this should only be considered a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean similar to how RAII is done in C++, the answer is no - Java insists you know when you no longer need something if you need to do something to clean it up. The usual way to do this is:

```
Something s = new Something();
try 
{
  // do things
} 
finally 
{ 
  s.close();
}
```

C# has a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword that tidies it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

While researching this I did come up with a near-solution. Essentially, when your Runnable is created, grab a copy of the thread that created you and occasionally check it's stacktrace. If it ever becomes empty you can safely assume they are finished ... or can you?

```
private void testThreads() throws InterruptedException {

  class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

    final Thread maker;

    private ThreadTest() {
      // Grab the maker's thread.
      maker = Thread.currentThread();
    }

    private boolean makerIsAlive() {
      // If maker's stack trace hits empty it is fair to assume they are done.
      return maker.getStackTrace().length != 0;
    }

    public void run() {
      // Keep checking the stack using a stacktrace.
      while (makerIsAlive()) {
        try {
          // Get out of here if maker has finished.
          // Wait one second.
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          break;
        }
      }
      System.out.println("====== Maker has finished! Exiting. ======");
    }
  }

  Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadTest());
  thread.start();
  // Wait for 10 seconds.
  long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000;
  while (System.currentTimeMillis() < finishTime) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
  }
}
```